# AngularJS binding doesn't work without filled parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to write a little application menu with angularJS.
Something like all windows applications have.

I tried to build this menu with angularJS 1.3.10.
The problem I am facing isn't so much of  a problem but more like a question regarding the internals.

I have two directives:

```
var chMenuModule = angular.module('chMenu',['chMenuItemModule']);
chMenuModule.controller('chMenuController', function ($scope) {
});

chMenuModule.directive('chMenu',['$document', function($document){
   return{
       restrict: 'E',
       template : '<div></div>',
       link : link,
       scope : {}
    };

    function link(scope,element,attrs)
    {

    }
}]);


var chMenuItemModule = angular.module('chMenuItemModule',[]);
chMenuItemModule.controller('chMenuItemController', function ($scope) {
});

chMenuItemModule.directive('chMenuItem',['$document', function($document){
   return{
       scope:{
           name : '@itemName'
       },
       restrict: 'E',
       template : '<button>{{name}}</button>',
       link : link,
    };

    function link(scope,element,attrs)
    {
    }
}]);
```

As you can see I left the first scope empty which leads to the problem that when I use those two directives like this:

```
    <ch-menu>
        <ch-menu-item item-name="File">
        </ch-menu-item>
        <ch-menu-item item-name="Edit">

        </ch-menu-item>
        <ch-menu-item item-name="View">

        </ch-menu-item>
        <ch-menu-item item-name="Help">

        </ch-menu-item>
    </ch-menu>
```

I don't see any texts in my buttons.
If I fill my first scope (the parent) with some blabla like this

```
scope:{bla:'blabla'}
```

The buttons are showed correctly.

inspecting this with the chrome shows me that with the empty scope the class of the buttons is  **ng-binding** but when i fill it with the blabla it is **ng-isolated-scope**.

Why do I have to fill the parent scope with values that i don't need or is there a smarter way of doing this ?

Here is a plunker in case you want to test what I mean http://plnkr.co/edit/RtzoNXbkTZkSuiPYlnFp?p=preview

Comment: I just saw that the above code I stated as working results in a Invalid Isolate Scope Definition. This Error makes my buttons show as I would expect... not nice though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have just forgotten 'transclude' option.

This might be what you want.

```
chMenuModule.directive('chMenu',['$document', function($document){
   return{
       restrict: 'E',
       template : '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
       transclude:true,
       link : link,
       scope : {}
    };

    function link(scope,element,attrs)
    {

    }
}]);
```

[plunker is here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/v9z3mEFdm7YOKS8Tvbgv?p=preview)

Comment: interesting, the plunker works but in my Netbeans environment it isn't working. There I use templateUrl and not template. I guess it shouldn't make a difference but it seems so. I will test that and let you know

Comment: Okay saw the error it was a typo. Okay thanks the answer was helpfull